# Module is not defined error while trying to call function in typescript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, typescript, requirejs

Sample code : Index.ts file which has reference of sample.ts

```
/// <reference path="sample.ts" />
var s: sample.Calculate = new sample.Calculate(5, 5); -- error thrown
s.alertme();
```

> Sample.ts file :

```
    module sample {
     export class Calculate {
        constructor(public x: number, public y: number) {
            console.log(x + y);
        }

        alertme() {
            alert('ok');
        }
    }
}
```

> Getting following error where i am calling calculate function :
>   [image]

PS: I am using visual studio 2015.
HTML:

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>MVC</h1>
    <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
    <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">

    </div>
</div>
@section scripts{    
    <script src="~/Scripts/typings/Index.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: How are you running this? In node or browser?

Comment: in browser by running it in debug mode

Comment: Seems like you're not using a module loader, can you add your `html` to the question?

Comment: added!!! i think as i am referencing the ts file module loader is not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `Sample.js` file isn't loaded to the browser and because of that the `sample` module isn't loaded.

Based on your code it seems that you want to load the scripts using script tags and not using a module system, if that's the case then all you need to do is:

```
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/typings/Sample.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/typings/Index.js"></script>
}
```

You did tag the question with `requirejs` so if you do mean to use that then you'll need to do:

```
// Sample.ts 
export module sample {
    ...
}

// Index.ts
/// <reference path="sample.ts" />
import sample = require('./Sample');
var s: sample.Calculate = new sample.Calculate(5, 5); // should be fine
```

You'll also need to add the "amd" module to your [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).
And you can read more about it in [the Modules section of the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

Comment: if i load the script in html itself then /// <reference path="sample.ts" /> is not required

Comment: It is required.  The `/// <reference` tags are not for actually loading the scripts, it's only for the compiler to use in order to find the definitions which are used, it's for compilation time only.

Comment: Oh. Well, yeah, since it's your file and the `.ts` file is there and not just the compiled `.js`. But if you'll try the same with a library you're using which lacks a `.ts` file then the reference is needed.

Comment: Sure, why not? go for it

Comment: i am importing module (AMD) :   import sample = require("./Sample")  In html i am referencing require js as  : <script src="~/Scripts/require.js" data-main="~/Scripts/typings/Index.js"></script>

Comment: but getting error as :  0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (require, exports, sample) {

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122571/discussion-between-sagar-k-and-nitzan-tomer).

Comment: In the future edit your question and add things there instead of putting the code in a comment like this, as this is not very readable. Also, this is more of a new question. Last: this looks to be quite a common issue, a quick google search for `Mismatched anonymous define()` will get you the answers you need, for example: [Common Errors](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch)

Comment: posted separate question  as not able o figure out the issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309242/getting-error-in-typescript-file-javascript-run-time-error-mismatched-anonymo